# Is there another code I can use instead of the "required" attribute when making drop-down menu?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a dropdown menu where the user should select an option before being able to continue. I tried this code with the "required" attribute but the user is still able to continue without selecting an option.
I tried the same attribute when I made an input box and there it worked fine.

```
   

<p class="line-item-property__field">
  <label>Indgravering i herre ring (Valgfrit)</label><br>
  <select required class="required" id="indgravering-i-herre-ring-valgfrit" name="properties[Indgravering i herre ring (Valgfrit)]">
    <option value="46">46</option>
    <option value="47">47</option>
    <option value="48">48</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an empty option value, otherwise the first option value is always selected anyway.

```html
<form action="something.php">
<p class="line-item-property__field">
  <label>Indgravering i herre ring (Valgfrit)</label><br>
  <select required class="required" id="indgravering-i-herre-ring-valgfrit" name="properties[Indgravering i herre ring (Valgfrit)]">
  <option value="">select something</option>
    <option value="46">46</option>
    <option value="47">47</option>
    <option value="48">48</option>
  </select>
</p>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```